# Execute Tokens in C: What does '.' and '/' mean in './'?

Tags: operating-system, token

When executing a C-program, we have to type a '.' token and a '/' token together followed by our program name:

```
./program
```

What do each of the these tokens mean?  Why do they need to be together to work?

Comment: This has nothing to do with **C**, its an _OS_ construction.

Comment: This is all to do with relative paths. read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)

Comment: @K-ballo if you want to be precise, it has nothing to do with the OS either, it's the _shell_ that interprets the path.

Comment: @mah: Paths are an _OS_ concept, not a _shell_ concept...

Comment: @K-ballo @mah I would argue neither and both, really. `~/foo` is a valid path in many shells. Some shells will translate `/foo` to `\foo` as appropriate (i.e. cygwin). Also some clients (i.e. browsers) may understand `file://` paths which the "OS" generally does not.

Comment: @pst: Thing is, we're not talking about `~`, and `file://` "paths" are technically not paths; they're URLs.  Paths might be translated a bit by the shell (like the `~` thing), but what ends up passed to the OS is still a path.  And an OS that gives each process a "current directory" (including Windows and Linux) could resolve `./program` without *any* help from the shell.

Answer (score 3):

The `./` syntax just refer to the current directory (Actually `.` is the current directory while `/` is the path separator). This is needed because the shell will look into folders specified in `$PATH` environment variable for executables. Since the program is in the current directory which is not inside PATH by default you need to specify the folder you are running it from.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this has nothing to do with C. This value is simply passed along to the operating system and used to locate a file.

But on Windows, it doesn't appear to have much meaning at all. `.` is the current directory and the `/` is simply the path separator between the current directory and `program`. Since the OS defaults to the current directory, it refers to the same path as just `program`.

Comment: In Windows, the current directory is checked first, then `%PATH%`.  So you don't need to say `./`.  \*nix, on the other hand, pretty much *only* checks `$PATH` when looking for stuff to run, unless you specify a directory.

Comment: It's ironic you say it's nothing to do with C.  Imagine never being able to execute a C program on the command line in Unix.  No, it could be by no means related whatsoever.

Comment: Say what? Under the covers that path is being sent to the operating system to locate a file. The operating system doesn't care if it came from the command line, a C program, or a program written in any other language. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`.` means current path

`..` means parent.

`/` means root or path separator. Depends on Unix/Windows/Mac

`./` means current path and relates, towards RHS.

`./Program` means PWD and Program as Directory or Location.

Comment: You should clarify your answer a bit... since clearly / does not mean root in all cases (such as in the question's use case).